# Using cvScalar of opencv with Ycbcr values

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to use the OpenCV function `cvInRange`, which need two `Scalar` parameters, and the problems is that I need to use a `YcbCr` values of the scalar min and max, does anybody know how to make this?

```
cvInRangeS(imgYCbcr,  
        cvScalar( Ymax, Cbmax, Crmax  ),  
        cvScalar( Ymin, Crmin, Crmin ), 
        imgThresh);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the problem? Is your image encoded in RGB?

Answer (score 1):

Convert image from `BGR` to `YCrCb` (see [`cvtColor`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor)) and use [`inRange`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#inrange) (not `cvInRangeS` - this is a `c` function, you need `c++`) function to get needed mask.

Comment: thanks Astor for your help, but it doesn't answer I wann to Y and Cb and Cr values and with cv::InRange I have the same problem

Comment: well to use cv::InRange(), I have to use cvSclar( ) twice My problem is the I'm working only with Y cbcr color Modell and for cvScalar I need HSV values ??  I hope it made this clear

Comment: Don't use `cvScalar` - it's a `c` style structure. Use `Scalar`. If you need only Y layer from YCrCb than use [`split`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#split) function. And I don't understand question about HSV.